# modal_progress_hud flutter package cannot be installed

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

i am trying to install this package "modal_progress_hud".
`modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3`
flutter pub get runs successfully but when i try to import the package, it doesn't work as it is shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQU8A.png).

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_project...                       0.6s
Process finished with exit code 0
```

i tried the same process with other packages and it works fine. is it because of the package or what might be the problem? i also ran flutter clean, pub cache repair, flutter pub upgrade, restart Android studio as well as my mac but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not your IDEA not analyzing the plugins? Try to import 
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart'; and run your code. And if it works but still shows the import in red then just restart the analysis of your project!

Comment: it didn't work, i even tried to install it on VS code but i had the same issue